# Necessity of coercivity assumption in Minty's theorem

Tags: operator-theory

Minty's Theorem states that a bounded, Continuous, monotone and coercive function on a Hilbert space is surjective.

A function $f:H\to H$ is called coercive if
$$ \lim_{\|x\|\to \infty} \frac{\langle f(x) , x \rangle}{\|x\|} =\infty $$

Is the coercivity assumption in Minty's theorem really necessary? If no, I need an example.

Comment: Are you sure that your definition of coercive is correct? (There are different definitions around - what you call coercive is also known as "strongly coercive".) Which this definition, coercivity is not necessary ($x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$). I known the theorem with the condition that $\langle f(x),x\rangle/\|x\|\to\infty$…

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked the definition of coercivity and it was as you mentioned. My question was that does there exist a non-coercive monotone function which is not surjective, but I found it very simple, for example $e^x$.